# terminate called throwing an exceptionAbort trap: 6

Tags: c++

I have the following code and when I compiled and went, I got following message

> terminate called throwing an exceptionAbort trap: 6

I looked for this ,but I was not able to understand this error message. Please tell me, what this error message means and how I fix the code.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n,r;
    while(cin>>n>>r){
        if(n==0&&r==0)break;
        string s;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            s[i]='i';

        for(int i=0;i<r;i++){
            int p,c;
            cin>>p>>c;
            string left=s.substr(p-1,p+c-1);
            string right=s.substr(0,p-2)+s.substr(p+c, (int)s.size());
            s=left+right;
        }
        cout << (int)(s[0]-'0')+1 << endl;
    }
        return 0;
}
```

compile with g++, on Mac OSX 10.7.4

Comment: Now is a good time for you to learn how to use the debugger. If you run your program in a debugger, it will tell you the location of the crash, and also let you examine variables to help you see what might have caused it. Regarding finding the location, you might have to check the callstack to find out where in your code it happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know where the exception comes from, but this just doesn't work

```
string s;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
    s[i]='i';
```

because the string is initially empty, and all `s[i]` will be out of bounds.

To add characters to the string in a loop, try

```
string s;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
    s.push_back('i');
```

If you just want a string with lots of `'i'`s, you can do that when constructing it:

```
string s(n, 'i');
```

Comment: string s;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) s += i;